# PHP - Correct way to compare radio button check against a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this database setup:

[image]

Alongside this code,

```
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM questions")){
    if($count = $result->num_rows){

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        echo $row->question, '<br><br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.$row->id.'" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">' . $row->ans1 . '</label><br/>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.$row->id.'" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">' . $row->ans2 . '</label><br/>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.$row->id.'" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">' . $row->ans3 . '</label><br/>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.$row->id.'" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">' . $row->ans4 . '</label><br/>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="q'.$row->id.'" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">' . $row->correct_ans . '</label><br/><br/>';

    }        
        $result->free();
    }
}
```

Which gives this output:

[image]

I was wondering, how could I check if the users answers against the correct answer stored in the database?

I figured it would be best to do an if statement and check if the correct answer was not selected. I'm just unsure how I would execute this, if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be of great help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: you would have to use some ajax call

Comment: Well I was mainly looking for theoretical advice but in terms of code. My main difficulty is to compare the users selected answer from each radio set with the correct answer in the database.

Answer (score 0):

just give the right answer a different value and then write a while loop that check the question's.

something like that (let's say every question has the name `q` and a number after it):

```
$count = 1;
$right_answers = 0;
while ($count <= 5)    {
    if ($_POST['q'.$count] == "right")    {
        $right_answers++;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

`$right_answers` is the counting of the right answers.

Comment: I don't understand why you would check if the radio button checked is equal to "right". Would it not be better to store the correct answer, for example : $answer = $row->correct_ans; Then check if the radio button is equal to this, rather than the word "right"?

Comment: @joemartin the `$_POST['q'.$count]` is returning the value of the `<input>`, you can store as value anything you want.

Answer (score -2):

take same name for all radio buttons but values should be different. on click of radio button you will get a value to be matched for checking.